# Eclipse cannot find the Google API's

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I updated my Google App Engine SDK on Eclipse as soon as I restarted Eclipse, the application couldn't resolve all the references to javax.* and com.google.* packages.

by searching the internet, I found how to restore the javax api's (by including the relevant jar located in the apache library), but I can't find any similar explanation about how to restore the Google api's.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the Google Plugin for Eclipse (GPE)? If not, consider it. All of the references that you need are included with the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen for newly created projects too? You could try Doing "project"->"Clean" or close and re-open the project to make sure all new dependencies are loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but I did a clean install of the latest version of JRE Eclipse and the Google App Engine SDK and it works ok now.